# transparent jpg?

Tags: adobe-indesign, transparency, background, jpg

This is my **jpg** photo with sky as background. I didn't do anything on it. there are no layers or layer masks. But when I place it in indesign, the background becomes transparent. I don't understand why. I thought indesign shows it that way because it is overwiev but it's transparent on the print too.
even if background of the pic was transparent, it should've turned white after converting to jpg. I don't understand.
I need my background blue as original. 
How can I fix it? 
[image]
[image]

Comment: Maybe this could help: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3J2ek6uVrx4
It might be something with InDesign's clipping path (type: detect edges)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You Should try checking InDesign's Clipping Path options.
That *could* be the problem.
If you select your object, and go to  Object= Clipping Path = Options you'll get this dialog box.

[image]

Make sure the type is set to None.

Hope it help :)